# VB.Net Class to CSV

Tags: vb.net

I am looking through the internet for a clean, straightforward way to convert a List collection of an entity class that I can convert to CSV. Basically, I am creating a web page that a user can enter in some parameters the MS SQL returns the results that are mapped to a class, which itself builds up a list. However, the results are not for display, but for saving to CSV.

Is there is a straightforward way to convert a List (of Entity) to CSV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any native CSV support in .NET, so if you can use XML instead of CSV it would be easier for you to serialize into XML. For CSV you need to write your own serializer.

Personally, I wrote functions that convert a DataTable into a CSV file and back. CSV is two-dimensional, so converting objects into the datatable first made sense to me.

If you want to go XML, then the serialization/deserialization routines for DataTable are built in: `DataTable.WriteXml()` and `DataTable.ReadXml()`

CSV has no standard, so I would recommend you mimic the Microsoft Excel version of CSV in the way it handles strings, escape characters etc. [This article](http://creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/CSV/CSV01.htm) is also very helpful for parsing.

Comment: Its ok now, we have now decided to do something else